# Trouble Connecting to LocalStack from GitLab CI Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, localstack

I'm trying to set up LocalStack within my GitLab CI pipeline, but I'm encountering connection issues. Here are the details:

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
test_glue_jobs:
  stage: test
  image: {MY_CUSTOM_IMAGE}
  variables:
    HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL: localstack
    DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: test
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: test
    SERVICES: dynamodb
  needs:
    - job: prepare_test_glue_jobs
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack:2.2.0
      alias: localstack
  script:
    - ...
    - aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localstack:4566
    - ...
```

I get the following error:
`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localstack:4566/"`

I've already tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Extending the wait time (sleep) before attempting to connect.
- Checking the configuration and environment variables.
- Using a different version of LocalStack.
- Testing locally outside GitLab CI, where everything works as expected.

I'm unsure about what might be causing this within the GitLab CI environment. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that spins up a LocalStack container on the CI job and allows you to execute AWS CLI commands:

```bash
image: docker:20.10.16

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: test
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: test
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME: localhost.localstack.cloud
    HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL: localhost.localstack.cloud


  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]

  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add gcc musl-dev linux-headers py3-pip python3 python3-dev curl
    - python3 -m pip install localstack awscli
  script:
    - docker pull localstack/localstack:latest
    # get IP address of docker host. localstack and all spawned containers will be reachable under that address
    - dind_ip="$(getent hosts docker | cut -d' ' -f1)"
    - echo "${dind_ip} localhost.localstack.cloud " >> /etc/hosts
    - cat /etc/hosts
    # start localstack
    - DOCKER_HOST="tcp://${dind_ip}:2375" localstack start -d
    - aws --endpoint http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 s3 mb s3://test
    - echo "hello world" > /tmp/hello-world
    - aws --endpoint http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 s3 cp /tmp/hello-world s3://test/hello-world
    - aws --endpoint http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 s3 ls s3://test/
```

The example is from the documentation — https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/ci/gitlab-ci/#setting-up-your-gitlab-ci-job

Here is a repository that allows you to validate this — https://gitlab.com/HarshCasper/localstack-test

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I see that the configuration you provided uses the docker:20.10.16 image as the base image. However, I need to use my custom image ${MY_CUSTOM_IMAGE} in my pipeline which is a centos based image.